# How display ajax data in select2.js v4.0?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using select2 v4.0  https://select2.github.io/ in an asp mvc  project and I want display a simple dropdown from dynamic Data

The old way of version 3.6 doesn't work anymore:

I have a c# methode:

```
public JsonResult GetSrcMethod()
 {
            var list = new[]
            { 
                new { id= 0, text= "Smith" },
                new { id= 1, text= "John" }, 
                new { id= 2, text= "Philippe" },    
            }.ToList();

            Object json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
            return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
 }
```

Thus, the data returned is:

```
[{"id":0,"text":"Smith"},{"id":1,"text":"John"},{"id":2,"text":"Philippe"}]
```

And I have  a javascript code which worked on previous version 3.6:

```
$(".example-select2").select2({
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSrcLanguages", "GetCheckSet")',
            results: function (data) {
                return {results: data};
            }              
        }
    });
```

It render an empty dropdownlist that displays 'No result found'

Do you know how to do it in v4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Id` is not the same as `id`, properties on JavaScript objects are case-sensitive. The same applies to `Text` and `text` as well, you want to use the all-lowercase versions.

```
public JsonResult GetSrcLanguages()
        {
            var list = new[]
            { 
                new { id = 0, text = "Smith" },
                new { id = 1, text = "John" }, 
                new { id = 2, text = "Philippe" },    
            }.ToList();

            Object json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
            return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
        }
```

Also, the `ajax.results` method was renamed to `ajax.processResults` in 4.0.0 to avoid conflicting with AJAX transports that have an existing `results` method. So your JavaScript should actually look like

```
$(".example-select2").select2({
    ajax: {
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetSrcLanguages", "GetCheckSet")',
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        }              
    }
});
```

Comment: thank, you are right but there is certainly another error because, after fix that error,  it is still showing 'No Result found' , allmost all things have changed vith v4 so I suppose results method is certainly depreciated and I am looking for new way to do that but I don't find it in doc

Comment: I replaced method  results: `function (data) {return {results: data};}`  by   `processResults: function (data) {return {results: JSON.parse(data)};} ` and it works!! thank you very much, you saw the mistake! If you update your answere by adding that sample of code, I would be happy to mark it as the answere! :D